# Centos 6.8 - Updates repo issues

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, mirror

I am running CenotOS 6.8 x64. Whenever I am trying to install something or update my packages I get below errors:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Determining fastest mirrors
epel-custom/metalink                                                                                                                       |  25 kB     00:00
 * base: ftp.pbone.net
 * centosplus: ftp.wcss.pl
 * epel-custom: ftp.pbone.net
 * extras: ftp.pbone.net
 * updates: ftp.wcss.pl
base                                                                                                                                       | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                                                                                                            | 4.7 MB     00:01
centosplus                                                                                                                                 | 3.4 kB     00:00
centosplus/primary_db                                                                                                                      | 1.4 MB     00:00
epel-custom                                                                                                                                | 4.3 kB     00:00
epel-custom/primary_db                                                                                                                     | 5.9 MB     00:00
extras                                                                                                                                     | 3.4 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                                                                                                          |  37 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-deps                                                                                                                            | 2.5 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-deps/primary_db                                                                                                                 |  27 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-deps-custom                                                                                                                     | 2.5 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-deps-custom/primary_db                                                                                                          |  27 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-products                                                                                                                        | 2.5 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-products/primary_db                                                                                                             | 170 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-products-custom                                                                                                                 | 2.5 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-products-custom/primary_db                                                                                                      | 170 kB     00:00
talanx                                                                                                                                     | 1.5 kB     00:00
talanx/primary                                                                                                                             | 6.2 kB     00:00
talanx                                                                                                                                                      18/18
talanx_custom                                                                                                                              | 1.5 kB     00:00
talanx_custom/primary                                                                                                                      | 1.9 kB     00:00
talanx_custom                                                                                                                                               12/12
updates                                                                                                                                    | 3.4 kB     00:00
http://ftp.wcss.pl/pub/linux/centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

http://centos.komster.pl/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror-pl.kielcetechnologypark.net/centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.hitme.net.pl/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos2.hti.pl/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos1.hti.pl/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/Linux/CentOS/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.po.opole.pl/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.prz.edu.pl/centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
ftp://ftp.man.szczecin.pl/pub/Linux/centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 19 - "Given file does not exist"
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.wcss.pl/pub/linux/centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.komster.pl/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror-pl.kielcetechnologypark.net/centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.hitme.net.pl/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos2.hti.pl/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos1.hti.pl/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/Linux/CentOS/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.po.opole.pl/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.prz.edu.pl/centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
ftp://ftp.man.szczecin.pl/pub/Linux/centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 19 - "Given file does not exist"
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2 from updates: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
 updates: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I have checked mirrors path for Updates repo and it looks like there was an update on 19th of October 2016. I have tried to fix this by running below commands:

```
yum clean all
yum clean metadata
yum update
```

but above didn't work. I know I can disable the repo, but this is not a solution for me as I need it. Did anyone come with similar issue?

thank you in Advance

**Edit**
Answer is:
Just in  case the problem was with incorrect date and time.

Comment: You may need to update the address specified in the `repo.conf` inside `/etc/yum.repos.d`.

Comment: I think I don't understand. I assueme you want me to edit e.g. CentOS-Base.repo. If yes,then I can say the address is ok. Nothing has changed in terms of config to yum.repos.d or yum.conf in /etc/ directory.

Comment: Ahh, yes. Sorry for this. My fault. What I meant is whenever update mirrors are looking for 7a5afcba7da77c73ceb53ea76c8d05a258d74d38bc0f63b0666a9ee8ebb58f99-primary.sqlite.bz2 it gives me 404 error. The reason is because it mirrors don't have it anymore. When I go to e.g. http://ftp.wcss.pl/pub/linux/centos/6.8/updates/x86_64/repodata/ I see that gz files where updates on 19st of October.

Comment: Oh now I understand. Sorry, I don't know where to modify the inputs to that code or if it is even possible.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was time and date drift which caused it.

Comment: what do you mean by time and date drift? and how did you solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I sorry for very late reply. But I think that my suggest may help other to solve this problem.

First of all you have to have a look at the **error message** from yum update that *which the repo crashes working process of yum*. For example in my case I had an issue with **home_dtufys** which shown in error message. Thus I already knew that I have to fix the problem by doing something with home_dtufys repo file.

... I go to this directory

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
```

... I list repo files which are stored in this directory and find the repo file that egarding with home_dtufys, then I saw **home:dtufys.repo**.

... Then I open the repo file that came across to the error from *yum update*

```
sudo vi home:dtufys.repo
```

... To disable the requesting this repo in next time of update, I changed the number 1 to 0 in enable line.

```
enable=0
```

... Then I save and exit and do yum update again.

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

Hope you and other user fix this problem.

Answer (score -1):

/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf
change 1 to 0 on the "enabled" option

yum clean all

yum update

After this you may enable fastestmirror plug in.

I've this issue too.